# Encryption enabled on Ubuntu Snappy Core

Tags: 16.04, security, encryption

Is there any kind of encryption enabled by default in the latest Ubuntu Snappy Core release?

Is the home dir encrypted? or other locations?

Comment: have a look at this artiche here: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/security-whitepaper/